# How to detect when a ComboBox's menu item is really selected by the user?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently facing the situation that if a user clicks on my ComboBox and moves the selection with his keys, the selection listener will keep being called, although for all purposes a choice was still not really made by the user.

How can I distinguish those "intermediate" selections from the proper, final, user selection in my ComboBox?

I tried looking at variables such as `isPopupVisible` or even playing with `PopupMenuListener` but they didn't seem to really help.

Thanks

Edit: Example of the offending code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {    
    public Main() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
        comboBox.addItemListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(e.getItem());
        });
        add(comboBox);
    }    
}
```

Comment: `ActionListener`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi, I already had tried that and it will fire every time the user moves his selection in the popup, so it's not good. I need something that only fires when the user actually clicks and the popup disappears.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, yes, that suggestion was given an hour ago.

Comment: whow...my apologies @camickr. I should refresh my web pages more often :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need something that only fires when the user actually clicks and the popup disappears.

```
comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Set the above property so the event is only generated on a mouse released or an Enter key.

Note:

1. if you use an `ActionListner` the event will always be generated when an item is selected.
2. if you use an `ItemListener` the event is only generated if you change the selected item from its previous selection.

Edit:

You could disable key selection by using:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( model )
{
    @Override
    public boolean selectWithKeyChar(char keyChar)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Edit 2:

Or maybe as a hack you can disable your listener when you do the key search. The code might be something like:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( model )
{
    @Override
    public boolean selectWithKeyChar(char keyChar)
    {
        // remove the listener here

        // This will cause the selected index to change
        Boolean result = super.selectWithKeyChar(keyChar);

        // add the listener back here

        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, it behaves exactly the same way as in the aforementioned cases.

Comment: You're a true master :zen:.

Comment: Unfortunately there's still a problem... if I type some character in the dropdown (to ease my search) it will still malfunction. Any ideas?

Comment: When you use the arrow keys the focus is on the JList used in the popup so you can select items in the JList without affecting the selection in the combo box (using the above suggestion). However, when you type in the editor, you are changing the selected item of the combo box, not just updating the selection in popup. I don't know how to change this as I suspect this behaviour is deep in the UI of the combo box.

Comment: @devouredelysium, see the second edit for a potential hack to allow key selection and prevent event from being generated.

Comment: I'll check it and I'll let you know. Thanks!